# sync part of my google drive

Tags: 18.04, google-drive

I'm new to Ubuntu (I hope I'll survive with the apps limitations).

I'm looking for way/client (Free) to sync with some directories of my Google drive, is it possible?

I found some clients (e.g. insync) but you should pay for their service. Also, the other available apps, you won't be allowed to sync part of Drive (only the whole directory).

Answer (score 1):

You can mount Google Drive on Ubuntu using [ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) via Nautilus.
But this does not provide syncing

GUI Sync tool:
Open source GUI tool for GDrive sync : [ODrive](https://liberodark.github.io/ODrive/)
There is a snap package for Odrive `sudo snap install odrive`
Dunno if you can select a specific drive folder for sync

CLI Tool:
Open source CLI tool for clouds rsync : [RClone](https://github.com/rclone/rclone)
RClone usage for Google Drive: https://rclone.org/drive/
It can select a specific drive folder for sync

Comment: ODrive will not work because of https://github.com/liberodark/ODrive/issues/147 . Full GUI sync with tray-icon is possible [with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198171/66509).

Comment: @N0rbert ODrive dev team will find a fix as RClone did. Wine must be aged in casks