# How does Ubuntu mount a Google Drive?

Tags: mount, 19.10, google-drive

There are a lot of tutorials on how to create a mount point for google drive around. They usually involve installing one tool or another and so on.

But ubuntu already has a GUI way to log in into your online accounts and mount the drive to access the files. I was wondering how does it do it, and how could I do the same through terminal so it uses the same credentials I already set instead of installing and configuring a whole new way to do it.

I am using ubuntu 19.10

Comment: For the most stable solution I can recommend the Q&A in [Grive2 is not functioning anymore, do we have alternative to get Google Drive working on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198170/grive2-is-not-functioning-anymore-do-we-have-alternative-to-get-google-drive-wo) . You can also try using GNOME Online Accounts in your modern system so set up Google Drive in Nautilus. I'm not sure is it working or not, will it auto-sync single or shared folders, or not.