# change google drive sync folder name

Tags: wine, playonlinux, google-drive

I installed Google drive sync app using play on linux. By default I did everything it prompted me to do, and ended up syncing my drive in documents/Google Drive (1).  I want to change the location of the drive sync and the folder name itself. To irritated to type all those slashes for spaces. Anyway to change it.

Moreover, Any manual way to force syncing to google server. Like a button or a command. For now, it is doing on it's own, But I want to manually do it sometimes.

Comment: This method is kind of trade-off. I simply remove virtual drive with GoogleEnterpriseSync application from PlayOnlinux, rename Google Drive folder to needed name and [start over](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198171/66509) (select Google Drive folder with correct path). About manual and control of the sync - it is very hard to get drop-down menu in the tray. I have tried many Windows versions in PlayOnLinux, but still no luck. So it is better than nothing. If you need stable cross-platform solution - take a look to DropBox.

Comment: @N0rbert that means there is no way that I can rename without starting over / installing again the application. cool.  Thanks for you, saved me a lot of time offering this when I am struggling with overgrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is kind of trade-off. I simply remove virtual drive with GoogleEnterpriseSync application from PlayOnlinux, rename Google Drive folder to needed name and [start over](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198171/66509) (select Google Drive folder with correct path). About manual and control of the sync - it is very hard to get drop-down menu in the tray. I have tried many Windows versions in PlayOnLinux, but still no luck. So it is better than nothing. If you need stable cross-platform solution - take a look to DropBox.