# Is there a way to have a windows-like google drive client?

Tags: mount, google-drive

You can mount your google drive into ubuntu by using gnome online accounts, but this has pretty low performance as it seems it has to download each file to open it and upload every time you want to save directly to it.

Is there a way to mount your google drive the way the windows client does it? Where the files are stored locally and, whenever there is a change locally or remotely, it syncs?

I also know of google-drive-ocalmfuse, but I am not sure if that one is syncing a local directory or mounting a remote one.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1198171/66509 , but it is kind of trade-off as it uses Wine.