# Installing a software written in Go

Tags: 20.04, git, golang

Id like to know how can I install [this software](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) which is written in Go. It's my first time that I download a software from git. Should I download the zip or can I copy the repository.

I will appreciate a procedure to manage this kind of software.

Comment: From the README: "*This tool is no longer maintained*." Previous last edit is four years old.

Comment: Also check https://askubuntu.com/q/161273/66509 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1198170/66509 . If you do not stick to Google Drive - switch to Dropbox as it is better integrated to DEs like GNOME or MATE.

Comment: Hello @N0rbert thank you very much for your suggestions. If you can, It'd be a great idea to make a YouTube video about your answer in the 2nd link.