# Google Drive in Ubuntu with full local copy

Tags: drive, google, google-drive, rclone

From OneDrive (Windows) or GoogleDrive (Windows) I am used to much more than I currently have in Ubuntu.

The built-in GNOME Online Accounts is not what I want. I've also tried other clients but all do not copy the whole Workspace locally, rather access every file in the cloud, just through the filesystem.

I want a Full local copy and only synchronization to the cloud.

Is there any tool i do not yet know of?

EDIT: found out about rclone but apparently this also does not provide full local copies.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Google Drive client available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161273/is-there-a-google-drive-client-available) . There are also more functional alternatives from Dropbox and MEGA.

Comment: Insync works well, but you have to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no Google Drive *client* for Linux.

There are many third-party applications that provide *some* Google Drive access. These are based upon the public Google API.

Those third party applications cannot provide *all* Google Drive client features, because the official client uses private methods that are simply not part of the public API.

Answer (score 1):

You may check out [VGrive](https://www.linuxlinks.com/vgrive-google-drive-client/). From the description it looks like it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you SO much. It is indeed what i want. Sadly i ran into a bug that it duplicated all files inside my drive, but in theory, it is exactly what i need.

Comment: From the GH repo, it looks old / unmaintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "rclone copy" to copy your Google Drive to a local folder and then write a bash script to sync this folder to your Google Drive using "rclone sync" and create a Cron job to run that bash every one hour.

Answer (score -1):

VGrive and ODrive seem like good options. However they failed for me at the Google login process.

Error 401:disabled_client. Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app. This app has not been verified yet ba Google in order to use Google Sign In.

- access_type: offline
- response_type: code
- redirect_uri: http://127.0.0.1:16409/authCallback
  client_id: 985525764653-m9dr93l4sme1ggp89fl28fopjas3equc.apps.googleusercontent.com
- scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Maybe this post could help: [Grive2 is not functioning anymore, do we have alternative to get Google Drive working on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198170/grive2-is-not-functioning-anymore-do-we-have-alternative-to-get-google-drive-wo?noredirect=1&lq=1)
It uses Wine/PlayOnLinux to install the Windows Client. I don't understand why there is no officially supported Drive Client for Linux-based systems, but it is what it is.

According to user N0rbert's answer from December 2019, the installation is fairly easy.

1. Install PlayOnLinux
   `sudo apt install playonlinux`
2. Launch PlayOnLinux.
3. Click **Install** or **Install a program**
4. Type "google drive" in the Search field and select **Google Drive Sync Enterprise**
5. Click **Install** and confirm.

The program should now be located on the Desktop or in **Applications > Internet > Google Drive Sync**

Please note that as of today (31.01.2023) on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS the download for the Program did not work. PlayOnLinux got itself the required Wine and Gecko packages, but was unable to download the file itself.

For some reason it tries to download WindowsXP

> https://web.archive.org/web/20150602122012/http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/c/abc45517-97a0-4cee-a362-1957be2f24e1/WindowsXP-KB975337-x86-ENU.exe

> Error! Files do not match.
>
> Local: ee4105f798ff522bc09bc1bcacc4596c
>
> Server: 946d00d87e4094f3a6e425e2d538eadd

Edit: Thanks Arthur for the comment. I'll try to include the main points. Sorry to user N0rbert for downright copying, but your description was well on point.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1277676)